# Saving an array of structs in Rails Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, rails-migrations

I would like to save an array of structs in PostgreSQL in rails in this format:

```
[#<struct User name=“Jack”, occupation=[“student”, "waiter"]>,
   #<struct User name=“Jason”, occupation=[“teacher”]>,
   #<struct User name=“Jeric”, occupation=[“athlete”, "trainer"]>,
   #<struct User name=“Jeffrey”, occupation=[“scientist”]>]
```

However, when I save them, I get the array in the format of string instead which is not what I want:

```
  ["#<struct User name=“Jack”, occupation=[“student”, "waiter"]>”,
   "#<struct User name=“Jason”, occupation=[“teacher”]>”,
   "#<struct User name=“Jeric”, occupation=[“athlete”, "trainer"]>”,
   "#<struct User name=“Jeffrey”, occupation=[“scientist”]>”]
```

In my migration file, I have done this:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :occupation, array: true, default: []
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When I change `t.string` to `t.array`, the database migration does not work.

I am wondering what kind of type should I give to the occupation column in my schema, and how should I write the migration file?

Comment: I'm assuming that an user could has multiple occupations(name, user_name)
I think that the easy way is create a new table 'Occupation' and then create the relationship with user table.

If you want use some datatype read here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array

To write the migration file you must do a rollback then change the migration file and run the migration again. 
If the migration file already is running on production you must create a new migration file that change old structure by the new.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? create a users table that will have database associations and save instances of users, or save a small collection of objects (that don't need relationships with other models) as an attribute of another table? and how are you currently saving the array of structs?

Comment: if you're just trying to create a users table in the database and be able to create and save new users then you're going about it the wrong way

Comment: I can't unsee this anymore

Comment: @m.simonborg These data are gotten from an API call. I have modified my question, the occupation attribute is actually an array of strings. The structs don't need relationships with other models. I would like to save the API data in my own database as an array of structs, but not as an array of strings.

Comment: @emaillenin Sorry, is the question really that bad?

Comment: @JeffreyYong checkout http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @JeffreyYong Yes, design your data model to store your data efficiently instead of dumping the actual object into DB